# Install libwebkitgtk for Linux

Tags: linux, centos, java-11

I ran this command on Linux (CentOS):

> sudo yum install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

but then I get this message:

> No package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 available.

> Error: nothing to do

Any suggestions? Trying to upgrade to Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

ihave tested with webkit2gtk3 on centos8,and it's executed without problem.

- yum install webkit2gtk3